# GdxRuntimeException: Asset not loaded

Tags: java, json, libgdx, asset-management

I'm following [this](http://saltares.com/blog/games/managing-groups-of-assets/) tutorial, but instead if xml i use json.
I think that the asset is loaded but apparently it's not! Would be nice if one of you have any solution.

[The code is on github.](https://github.com/Zuck3rwatt3/CardGamePrototype)

That is the output:

```
SUCCESS!
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Asset not loaded: core\assets\badlogic.jpg
    at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager.get(AssetManager.java:150)
    at epytotorp.managers.AssetManager.get(AssetManager.java:78)
    at epytotorp.Game.create(Game.java:18)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:149)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:126)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I tryed many thinks but none of them worked can you pls help me.
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the Java libraries for dealing with files, you can safely use / (slash, not backslash) on all platforms. The library code handles translating things into platform-specific paths internally.

I made some modification in your `create()` method of your Game game and then it's works.

```
@Override
public void create() {
    AssetManager.getInstance().initialize("core/assets/test.json");
    AssetManager.getInstance().load("group 1");
    AssetManager.getInstance().finishLoading();
    System.out.println("SUCCESS!");
    Texture texture = AssetManager.getInstance().get("core/assets/badlogic.jpg", Texture.class);

    System.out.println("Texture"+texture);

    ScreenManager.getInstance().initialize(this);
    ScreenManager.getInstance().setScreen(ScreenEnum.SPLASH);
}
```